# Cron job not working on Lumen using Nanobox

Tags: laravel, cron, scheduler, lumen

I am trying to write a cron job in nanobox. I have implemented some logic in Kernel.php and made respective changes in boxfile.yml file. After this my scheduled job is expected to run every hour but its not running. I dont know what am I missing here.

Relevant part of my boxfile.yml looks like below

```
  cron:
    - id: scheduleForRSS
      schedule: '0 * * * *'
      command: 'php artisan schedule:run'
```

My  Kernel.php file have following class

```
class Kernel extends ConsoleKernel
{
    /**
     * The Artisan commands provided by your application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $commands = [
        //
    ];

    /**
     * Define the application's command schedule.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule  $schedule
     * @return void
     */
    protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
        $schedule->call(function () {
            //DB::table('keyword')->delete();
            echo "Hello, from Kernel.schedule !";
            DB::table('xyz')->insert([
                ['title' => 'abc', 'value' => 0]            
            ]);
        })->everyMinute();
    }
}
```

When I run following command however, schedule function is called and I can see output on console as well as a record is getting inserted into DB, proving the function is implemented correctly and doing what it is supposed to do. Its just that, for some reason its not getting called from nanobox's cron job functionality.

```
/app $ *php artisan schedule:run*

Running scheduled command: Closure
Hello, from Kernel.schedule !
```

Comment: does it need a fuller path to artisan ?

Comment: @lagbox, I dont think, as I am running it from my app root, it should work without full path too. Anyways I will quickly check and revert back with my findings

Comment: @lagbox, it does not work even :(

Comment: you are not running it, cron is running it, cron runs from the root of your project?

Answer (score 0):

Got it sorted, cron-jobs dont run on local machine. When I deployed it on server (aws in my case) jobs started to run.